# sqlite3 - making the combination of two entries unique

Tags: arrays, sqlite, unique

Table:

```
Car | Year | Colour
---------------
=
BMW  | 2013  | Black

Benz | 2011  | Red

BMW  | 2011  | Orange
```

As you can see, neither 'Car' nor 'Year' columns are unique. But how can I make the combination of Car and Make unique such that this table doesn't accept any other (BMW, 2013, whatever_colour) entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can do either:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON TableName(Car,Year)
```

or you can re-create the table with a `PRIMARY KEY` on `(Car, Year)`.  If you have other tables that identify models with the `Car, Year` combination and you want to ensure that those pairs are checked against the main table, the `PRIMARY KEY` is the preferred solution (with matching `FOREIGN KEY`s declared on the other table(s)).

Comment: But if I already have used the PRIMARY KEY for ID, can I have another PRIMARY KEY in the table? like 'CREATE TABLE HEADERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (HEADERS ,UNIT)'? Thanks for the help Larry :)

Comment: No, only one PRIMARY KEY.  So, in this case you will use the UNIQUE INDEX solution, which is allowed.  You might also consider abandoning the ID column in place of an "intelligent" PRIMARY KEY on (Car, Year), although many developers prefer the ID solution.